# Squarespace like handlebars templating approach

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have grown to appreciate the simplicity of handlebars js templating however there is one thing about it I still feel to be abit convuluted and was wondering if there was a simplier solution.

Problem:

The simple way of setting up handlebars

```
// Extract the text from the template .html() is the jquery helper method for that
  var raw_template = $('#simple-template').html();
  // Compile that into an handlebars template
  var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
  // Retrieve the placeHolder where the Posts will be displayed 
  var placeHolder = $("#main");
  // Create a context to render the template
  var context = {posts: 
    [
      {title: "First Post", entry: "You can't stop me now!", author: "Sandy Duster"},
      {title: "2nd Post",   entry: "Alice you are going in the wrong way."},
      {title: "3rd Post",   entry: "Mate, Where is my burger?"},
      {title: "4th Post",   entry: "The rainmaker day"},
    ]
  }
  // Generate the HTML for the template
  var html = template(context);
  // Render the posts into the page
  placeHolder.append(html);
```

Everything above is currently whats required to add content into ONE container id (#main) using ONE handlebars template.

If I decided to add content to more containers using different templates I would have to compile it, retrieve the placeholder container, generate the html for the template, and append it inside the placeholder. I would have to do that for every single different template file.

My IDEAL scenario would be to call context or JSON data ONCE:

```
var context = {posts: 
    [
      {title: "First Post", entry: "You can't stop me now!", author: "Sandy Duster"},
      {title: "2nd Post",   entry: "Alice you are going in the wrong way."},
      {title: "3rd Post",   entry: "Mate, Where is my burger?"},
      {title: "4th Post",   entry: "The rainmaker day"},
    ]
  }
```

And then to SIMPLY go through the content inside body and insert {{page[0].name}}, {{imageURL}}, add content blocks and etc without having to INDIVIDUALLY define templates. Simple like how wordpress queries its post and displays content, query the database once and go through the page adding in pieces of queried content.

The squarespace developers platform works similar to this way, You don't have to insert templates or compile and render, you simply go through your html adding in {{.section title}}.

So my question is, is there a simple squarespace like method available that I could adopt? Or is squarespace simply had heavy backend code developed to allow for this kind of convenience?

Sorry if this sounds like a confusing problem, I just want the simplest way to:

```
 SCRIPT TO LOAD JSON CONTENT
<body>
    {INCLUDE HEADER BLOCK HERE}
    <h1>{ADD TITLE HERE}</h1>
    {ADD CONTENT HERE}
    </body>
```

without the repetitive compiling, defining container variables, rendering.

Comment: You could take that entire blob of code and put it in a function that looks like this: `render('#main', '#simple_template', context)`

Comment: So what you're suggesting is I could simply do

`render('#main', '#simple_template', context);`
`render('#work', '#work_template', context);`
`render('#header', '#header_template', context);`
`render('#footer', '#footer_template', context);`

If I were to keep these #_template files seperate as a means of better template management Is there a way to easily include .handlebars templates? Would I have to rely on AJAX request to do that? eg
`var template = function to import template.handlebars content`
`render('#footer', template, context);`